# PHP Cookie: "/" not allowing to access cookie in other directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I have set the cookie in the following manner in my code:

```
setcookie("email_id",$result->email,0,"/","",0);
```

I am working on "localhost" and so I have set the domain to "".

I am using codeigniter framework with the following folder structure:

```
/
/application
/xyz
index.php
and so on..
```

I want to access a cookie set in my controller in my "xyz" folder. I am unable to retrieve the value there. The set cookie however shows up in the browser.

Comment: Try not passing any value for `$domain` and `$secure`.

Comment: Hi Rob, i tried the same but no success :(

Comment: In which directory do you set the cookie? Are you able to retrive the cookie in the same directory where you set it?

Comment: Yes i am able to retrieve the cookie in the same directory...i am setting the cookie in the Controller which is inside the application folder.